# how to execute third elif condition?

Tags: python-3.x, if-statement

I'm building a hangman game and want to check for "legal characters".
If the player entered more then one sign, it should print `"E1"`.
If he entered something other then `a-z` - print `"E2"`.
And if he entered more then one sign and not an `a-z` letter print `"E3"`
I cant get to `"E3"`. Why is this happening and what am I doing wrong?

```py
import string
player_input = input("Guess a letter: ").lower()
aToz = string.ascii_lowercase[0:26]


if len(player_input) != 1:
    print("E1")
elif player_input not in aToz:
    print("E2")
elif player_input not in aToz and len(player_input) != 1:
    print("E3")
else:
    print(player_input)
```

Expected result is to get `"E3"` when typing more then one letter and some other sign. The actual result is `"E1"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error case "entered more than one sign" is a more general case than "entered more than one sign & not any letter a-z". Anything which satisfies the condition for `E3` will always satisfy the condition for `E1`. Since you have defined the more general case `E1` **before** `E3`, you always get `E1`

To fix this, you can move the condition for E3 to the top of the if-else ladder and the case for E1 to the bottom.

```
if player_input not in aToz and len(player_input) != 1:
    print("E3")
elif len(player_input) != 1:
    print("E1")
elif player_input not in aToz:
    print("E2")
else:
    print(player_input)
```

Note: the condition `player_input not in aToz` will never be `True` for multi-character inputs so the second check is sort of redundant.

Answer (score 0):

The `if`/`elif` statements are evaluated sequentially. So if one of the conditions are already met (in your case the first `len(player_input) != 1`), the code will run that block and not evaluate the remaining `elif` or `else` blocks. In the simple case you gave, you'd have to reorder the statements like so:

```
if player_input not in aToz and len(player_input) != 1:
    print("E3")
elif len(player_input) != 1:
    print("E1")
elif player_input not in aToz:
    print("E2")
else:
    print(player_input)
```

Answer (score 0):

The execution flows from first IF-Block, i.e if there are multiple characters, it won't check for E3 expection..

and after that it'll flow to the next ELIF-Block, i.e if there are special characters..

If you see the code coverage, it'll never reach the third block.

And it's not even required. Your first two error checks, can handle that pretty well.

However you would still like to have that exception in your test case, you need to first check for E3, and then proceed to E1 and E2

Something like this:

```
if player_input not in aToz and len(player_input) != 1:
    print("Error: Multiple characters and Special characters")
elif len(player_input) != 1:
    print("Multiple Characters")
elif player_input not in aToz:
    print("Special Character")
else:
    print(player_input)
```

Comment: Looks like everyone posted the same answer!
I' might as well take  my answer down.